# Rewrite rewritten (and redirected) url

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Symfony2 API, for which I made a seperate GUI. The part of .htaccess below works. When url/api is called, request will be passed to the API, when just the url is called, the gui will be opened with a redirect to /app.

Redirect to /app is, because I have a symbolic link in my Symfony2 /web directory that links to the GUI. (app -> ../gui)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api/
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app/$1 [R,L,QSA,NE]
```

What I want, is that the /app disappears from my url, but that the requests are served trough that symbolic link.

A simple rewrite I made did not work, because the url still states /app in it.

This offcourse does also not work:

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}../gui/$1 [R,L,QSA,NE]
```

Any tips?